# Implement a delay in Java

Tags: java

Hi I have the following code:

```
okBtn.addEventListener(Events.ON_CLICK, new EventListener()
{
            @Override
            public void onEvent(final Event arg0) throws Exception
            {
                //when the user clicks on ok, we take the current 
                //string from fckeditor...
                String currentValue = fckEditor.getValue();
                // set the string to preview to the current value 
                html.setContent(currentValue);

            }
 });
```

The problem I am facing is that there is a delay in this fckEditor.getValue() (the fckEditor is similar to a textArea) call because the ok action is faster than what fckEditor.getValue() takes to retrieve the data and in consequence sometimes when I modified the text in fckEditor really fast and hit the okBtn the changes are not reflected.

I came up with this solution,

```
    okBtn.addEventListener(Events.ON_CLICK, new EventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(final Event arg0) throws Exception
        {

            String currentValue;

            synchronized (fckEditor)
            {
                currentValue = fckEditor.getValue();
                fckEditor.wait(100);
            }

            html.setContent(currentValue);

        }

    });
```

However, I am not fully convinced this will be the best solution because I am hard coding the delay `.wait(100);` and problably delays might differ in different computers. So eventually other environments might require more or less delay.

How can make the execution wait until the `fckEditor.getValue();` call has been completely finished? and so `currentValue` can hold the right String and be saved properly?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
Timer timer = new Timer() {
 public void actionerformed() {
   setRepeats( false );
   String currentValue = fckEditor.getValue();
   try {
      Thread.sleep( 100 );
   } catch( Exception ex ) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
   }//catch
   html.setContent(currentValue);
 }//met
}//inner class
timer.start();
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment but may be I didnt make myself clear. My problem is that I dont want to hard code the delay to any value in this case 100. Rather find a way to wait until the method call is finished

Comment: In that case, you should modify the code of getValue to wait until it actually really holds a value and return it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use wait without a parameter and let the executor call `notify` or `notifyAll` when it finishes the execution.

---

In accordance with  Marko Topolnik's suggestion a very simple example:

```
//declaration
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
...
//in the executor thread
latch.countDown();
//in the waiting thread
exec.start();
latch.await();
```

Comment: Search for "A correct implementation of a producer and consumer" [Here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=306) (without the quotes).

Comment: No, please recommend `CountDownLatch` to people for this use case. An order of magnitude simpler to use -- and actually just **simple** to use!